# Show Sale Data By Salesman By Region

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need a SQL Server query to show a grid of sales by region by sales person like this:

```
region   Mitchell   Mark    Manny     Moe
-----------------------------------------
West        0        0        0        0
North       0        1        1        1
East        1        0        0        0
South       0        0        0        0
```

How can I have my SQL query output the data like this? I know I could use this to return the data but it is not in the correct breakdown or format.

```
Select region, salesperson, Count(Sales)
from salesdatabase
group by region, salesperson
```

Comment: *PIVOT* is your friend.

Comment: @king.code SQL Server Pivot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can *PIVOT* your table. Try this:

```
;WITH DATA AS
(
    SELECT region, salesperson, Sales
    FROM salesdatabase
)
SELECT region
      ,[Mitchell]
      ,[Mark]
      ,[Manny]
      ,[Moe]
FROM DATA AS D
PIVOT (COUNT(Sales) FOR salesperson IN ([Mitchell], [Mark], [Manny], [Moe])) AS P;
```

You can find more information [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

Comment: I have never seen this SQL Function and I LOVE IT!  Thank you for that invaluable piece of info